# TypeError when using scipy.optimize.fsolve in Python 2.6

Tags: python, scipy, decimal

I try to solve a very complex nonlinear equation by using fsolve method but facing a problem that I couldn't use decimal module...

Error message:
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Code:( I already simplified fun().)

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext

def fun(x, *data):
    a, b = data
    return x**a + b*x**Decimal(str(0.5))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Decimal(str(330.86/2.0))
    b =  Decimal(str(225.96/2.0))
    data = (a,b)
    EE = fsolve(func=fun,x0=Decimal(str(1)),args=data)
    print EE
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `numpy` doesn't play well with the `Decimal` type.  If you just use regular `floats` it should work fine.

Comment: Then you can't use numpy.

Comment: Can you convert to floats just to use numpy, then convert back to Decimal?

Comment: But I need to use decimal type...because another numerical problem...
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help. Unfortunately these two things are incompatible.